# Download file from PHP query headlessly

Tags: php, python, python-requests

I am running a Python script that needs to download a file from URL that runs a PHP query:

```
url = "https://blah.com//file.php?file=FileName&params=query=SomeQuery"
```

In an actual browser, given that you're logged in to the site, going to that URL initiates a download for the file (.csv).

How can I download this file through my script, using `requests`? Something like:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()  # we log in using this session elsewhere so authentication shouldn't be a problem
response = s.get(url)

with open("my_file.csv", "w") as f:
    write(response.data, f)  # pseudo code
```

I can't seem to initiate the download. Do I need to see what headers I need to pass?

Comment: Can you run the python script on the command line - and does it download the file as expected?

Comment: I am doing so already, and it is not working. I need to get the `requests` module to `GET` the file correctly. I am expecting either a `JSON` format or something else...

Comment: at a guess the website is going out of its way to prevent the behaviour you are attempting(probably utilizing javascript stuffs) ... without knowing exactly which website you are unlikely to get any further help (and even if we know the exact website you are trying to download from this behaviour is typically frowned on and so may not get answered)

Comment: Ok, let's stick from the command line, then migrate to the web app. Is there any output produced from your script? Is the variable 'url' properly set to a valid url?

Comment: No web app here, just a Python script that will be running on a server. No output at the moment. The `response` variable doesn't contain any data, apart from the HTML of the page.

Comment: Is the php file setting a content-type header?

Comment: From what I can see in Chrome, the Reponse Headers contain `Content-Type:application/json`. But the Request Headers do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (slight variation of your code) appears to work fine.

```
import requests
url = "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get(url)

with open("my_file.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(response.content)
    f.close()
```

Comment: This is different from my case, as my URL contains a PHP query.

Comment: It shouldn't really make any difference what it's fetching. However, perhaps what's happening is that the response varies by user-agent - such as returning a 302 redirect. What do you get when you run (from command line) wget -S [your site and php url] Do you see a redirect?